# How to make responsive design in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am building an app in javaFx but the problem is my app doesn't resize, if I open the app the small window is which is fine but when I maximize the window the app content(table) doesn't resize accordingly.
here is my fxml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ch.Buildsapp.Main.BuildsController">
    <children>
        <ComboBox fx:id="versionCombo" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="14.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="7.0 Win">
          <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
          <String fx:value="Win" />
          <String fx:value="Mac" />
          </FXCollections>
      </items>
            <value>
        <String fx:value="Win" />
    </value>
        </ComboBox>
        <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="52.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="builds" prefWidth="482.0" text="Builds" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="date" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="124.0" text="Date" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="release" prefWidth="167.0" text="Release" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
        <Button fx:id="downloadButton" layoutX="328.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Download" />
        <Button fx:id="installButton" layoutX="458.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Install" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="locCombo" layoutX="636.0" layoutY="14.0" prefWidth="150.0">
      <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
          <String fx:value="CJ" />
          <String fx:value="MN" />
          </FXCollections>
      </items>
      <value>
        <String fx:value="CJ" />
    </value>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="versionNo" layoutX="177.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="122.0" promptText="7.0" />

    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

here is code for binding.

```
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("BuildsView.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        rootLayout.sceneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Scene>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> observable,
                        Scene oldValue, Scene newValue) {
                    rootLayout.prefWidthProperty().bind(newValue.widthProperty());
                    rootLayout.prefHeightProperty().bind(newValue.heightProperty());
                }
            });
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [Layout Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) that lays the controls out the way you want, instead of hard-coding the positions in an `AnchorPane`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**2nd Edit**

Initial solution had the fix without noting.

Your problem was because you had not really specified how your `TableView` should be layed out in your `AnchorPane`. By default children in `AnchorPane` are layed out Top-Left and they are left to grow wide and long based on their `Width` and `height` if they can.

That is why your `Tableview` was not very much responding the way you wanted it

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="52.0">//setLayout should not be use here
```

as you can see you did not specify constraint for your TableView hence they followed the default

however in my solution since I did not copy paste your `fxml` but tried to lay it out personally i did not really noticed your error and stuck to my *untested-offhead* solution which was `bind` but the real solution is

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" 
       AnchorPane.leftAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
```

as you can see they have constraints and very much different from yours, and my old edit had that.

so sorry for the 6months bs i posted.

**1st EDIT**

sorry for the delay. but something like this.

fyi: i removed the controller id. so compare and make your adjustment

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
 import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
 import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;


 public class Main extends Application {
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("pane.fxml"));
        AnchorPane rootLayout = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        //rootLayout.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty()); not needed
        //rootLayout.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());in these scenario
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}
}
```

THen the fxml, i called mine `pane`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
  <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="14.0" spacing="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
          <ComboBox fx:id="versionCombo" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="7.0 Win">
            <items>
          <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Win" />
            <String fx:value="Mac" />
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
              <value>
          <String fx:value="Win" />
      </value>
          </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox fx:id="versionNo" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="122.0" promptText="7.0" />
          <Button fx:id="downloadButton" minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Download" />
          <Button fx:id="installButton" minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Install" />
        <ComboBox fx:id="locCombo" prefWidth="150.0">
        <items>
          <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="CJ" />
            <String fx:value="MN" />
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
        <value>
          <String fx:value="CJ" />
      </value>
        </ComboBox>
     </children>
     <padding>
        <Insets left="10.0" right="3.0" top="5.0" />
     </padding>
  </HBox>
    <TableView fx:id="tableView" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="builds" prefWidth="482.0" text="Builds" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="date" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="124.0" text="Date" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="release" prefWidth="167.0" text="Release" />
        </columns>
    </TableView>

 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: @EIltz    I tried this:-    double orgW = 1000;
   double orgH = 800;
   Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
   rootLayout.scaleXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(orgW));
            rootLayout.scaleYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().divide(orgH));  but UI breaks like it is being compressed when screen is small and is moves out of the screen when screen is maximized.

Comment: @EIItz thanks, I have edited my question with the way I am implementing it, after using your code also I am seeing the issue which I was facing initially. Can you see where I am wrong ??

Comment: Since this question and answer seems to be getting linked quite a lot, I want to point out that the they don't really make much sense. The root node of the scene will always take on the dimensions of the scene: its `min/pref/maxWidth` and `min/pref/maxHeight` are ignored. So it makes no sense at all to bind the `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` of the root of the scene to anything. If you comment those lines out, nothing changes. It's not really clear what the question means anyway: there is no specification of *how* the OP wants the UI to respond, and how it is different to what it's doing anyway.

Comment: _answer..getting linked..lot_ where & where ? **but Thank you very much,** i overlooked,  it was an _fxml_ configuration that caused the problem, which i fixed without noting it the answer **Thanks** will make an edit@James_D

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
 <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="52.0" 
AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
```

Answer (score -3):

you have to set all the constraints to 0. check it out