# How to properly turn custom button set into a responsive object?

Tags: java, javafx, layout, responsive-design

**Introduction**

I am learning how to do responsive a UI with `JavaFX 11` for future projects and came up with this doubt about designing a responsive layout.

**Problem**

[Custom Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np8wY.png)

I have built this custom layout which contains two labels and a button, the hierarchy is:

[Custom Layout Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSMAX.png)

When I set the app to fullscreen it turns into an unwanted result. The labels and button inside the custom layout stay fixed and do not move with resizing when on fullscreen mode.

[Fullscreen unwanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQjre.png)

Shown in red, there is an undesired white space where I want the items to move into.

**How can I do it so the items inside translate accordingly to resize?**

**Sources visited**

- [how to make resposive design - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936072/how-to-make-responsive-design-in-javafx)
- [using anchor for resize - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335889/javafx-responsive-tableview)
- [GUI garage - Blog for JavaFX](https://guigarage.com/2015/09/how-to-create-a-responsive-layout-in-javafx/)

**FXML**

```
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="880.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.GUI.controller.BioJavaController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar>
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="728.0" prefWidth="883.0">
         <items>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <LineChart fx:id="LineChart" prefHeight="358.0" prefWidth="878.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <xAxis>
                      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                      <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                    </yAxis>
                  </LineChart>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" prefHeight="333.0" prefWidth="878.0">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="measurePanel" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="436.0" prefWidth="349.0">
                     <children>
                        <ToolBar fx:id="ToolPoint_1" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="393.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-1.0">
                           <items>
                              <AnchorPane prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="393.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button fx:id="measureBtn_1" layoutX="317.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#onMeasureClick" text="Count" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="317.0" />
                                    <Label layoutY="9.0" text="Counter" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" />
                                    <Label layoutX="132.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="261.0" text="Number: 0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="132.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </items>
                        </ToolBar>
                        <ToolBar fx:id="ToolPoint_11" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="436.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                           <items>
                              <AnchorPane prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="393.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button fx:id="measureBtn_11" layoutX="317.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#onMeasureClick" text="Count" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="317.0" />
                                    <Label layoutY="9.0" text="Counter" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
                                    <Label layoutX="132.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="261.0" text="Number: 0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="132.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </items>
                        </ToolBar>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="handPanel" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="286.0" fitWidth="252.0" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="-3.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@Estilo/Elegant.PNG" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Why don't you try some of the solutions you linked in your question?

Comment: @James_D I did try, but I did not get my desired result.

Comment: @kleopatra You are totally right, noted. Thanks to point it out.

Comment: Why did you use a `ToolBar` then put an `AnchorPane` in it and add three `Nodes` to the `AnchorPane`? I would replace the `ToolBar` with `HBox` and add the three `Nodes` to the `HBox.

Comment: @Sedrick I use the anchor pane to use the "anchor pane constraints" (Scene Builder) to keep things in place

Comment: In your situation, `AnchorPane` is not the node for you.

Comment: @Sedrick  Could I ask for an example on how to achieve the custom button that I tried to build incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace the `ToolBar` with `HBox` and add the three `Nodes` to the `HBox`. I would then use `CSS` to get the style I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="880.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.GUI.controller.BioJavaController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar>
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="728.0" prefWidth="883.0">
         <items>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <LineChart fx:id="LineChart" prefHeight="358.0" prefWidth="878.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <xAxis>
                      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                      <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                    </yAxis>
                  </LineChart>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5, 0.5" prefHeight="333.0" prefWidth="878.0">
              <items>
                  <VBox>
                     <children>
                        <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" style="-fx-background-color: #707070,        linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #f3f3f3),        linear-gradient(#f2f2f2 0%, #ebebeb 49%, #dddddd 50%, #cfcfcf 100%); -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;; -fx-background-radius: 3,2,1;; -fx-padding: 3 30 3 30;; -fx-text-fill: black;;">
                           <children>
                              <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Counter" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                              <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Number: 0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                              <Button fx:id="measureBtn_1" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#onMeasureClick" text="Count" />
                           </children>
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" style="-fx-background-color: #707070,        linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #f3f3f3),        linear-gradient(#f2f2f2 0%, #ebebeb 49%, #dddddd 50%, #cfcfcf 100%); -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;; -fx-background-radius: 3,2,1;; -fx-padding: 3 30 3 30;; -fx-text-fill: black;;">
                           <children>
                              <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Counter" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                              <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Number: 0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                              <Button fx:id="measureBtn_12" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#onMeasureClick" text="Count" />
                           </children>
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </HBox>
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="handPanel" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="286.0" fitWidth="252.0" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="-3.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@Estilo/Elegant.PNG" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                  <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                    <items>
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                    </items>
                  </ToolBar>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Normal**
[image: Normal]

**Full Screen**
[image: Full Screen]

Style code from: http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to study the answer and link right away. I accept your solution.